# JDK will not run on my Mac

Tags: macos, oracle, java

I recently downloaded jdk 7u25 on my Mac (I run an OSX 10.7.5) for my java developers class. After downloading the .dmg file from Oracle at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
and after successfully installing the package, I tried to open it at Library>Java>JavaVirtualMachines>jdk1.7.0_25.jdk>Contents>Home>MacOS>libjli.dylib

After opening on Terminal (default program), I got a short message looking like this:

```
 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib ; exit;
-bash: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib: cannot execute binary file
logout

[Process completed]
```

I probably did something wrong here, but I have no way of finding out as all the FAQs on Oracle are extremely vague and basic, or all the answers on forums are beyond my knowledge of java.

I am very much a beginner, and I just want to run the same jdk on my laptop like I do at school so that I can take my work home.

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Start a command prompt with Java in your path?

Comment: Why do you think `Library>Java>JavaVirtualMachines>jdk1.7.0_25.jdk>Contents>Home>MacOS>libjli.dylib` will run anything? Where did you get this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Applications -> Utilties -> Terminal

On the command line type:

java --version

That will tell you the installed jdk version.

Comment: `java -version` (single dash)